# How to replace equal consecutive numbers in a list to nan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm trying to replace equal consecutive numbers in a list to nan. I having problems to replace all values when there is a odd number of equal consecutive numbers.

This is my code, very simple:

```
list= [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]

for i in range(0,len(list)):
    if list[i] == list[i-1]:
    list[i] = list[i-1] = np.nan

Out: [nan, nan, nan, nan, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3, nan, nan, 5]
```

Another question, if I want to replace only those values that repeated more than 3 times, for example the numbers 1 or 2 that are repeated 5 and 4 times respectively.

This is what I want:

```
Out: [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Could you add what your desired output would look like?

Comment: Is the list going to be always sorted?

Comment: Ishwar just updated the post.

Comment: Ankur, no, the list will not be sorted. The list in the post is just an example for the code.

Comment: @tonysg What is the expected output for: `[1,2,2,2,1,1]`?

Comment: Ankur, I just updated the post with the desired output. Someone has already answer me and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Counter` to keep track of elements in list and use `list comprehension` with condition

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

list1 = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
counter = Counter(list1)

list_new = [np.nan if counter[i] > 3 else i for i in list1]
print(list_new)
```

Output:

```
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

**Alternate solution**

```
from itertools import groupby
b = [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(list1)]

list2 = []
for i,j in b:
    if j > 3:
        list2.extend([np.nan]*j)
    else:
        list2.extend([i]*j)

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know Counter exists. That solve my question, thank you again.

Comment: Explore `collections` and `itertools` modules, it will make your life much easier. Happy coding :-)

Comment: Theres a problem, if a number appeared multiple times in different positions, it will change the numbers. For example list = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,3], the last number (3) will change to nan, but it isnt an equal consecutive number with the previous one (5).

Comment: Definetily will explore them :)

Comment: @tonysg I have provided alternate solution to overcome that issue